# Split dataframe into multiple dataframe based on NaN value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, bigdata

my question refers to the separation of dataframes into multiple dataframes.
The original dataframe is shown in [*FIGURE_1*]. It should be split at a certain value, e.g. NaN [*FIGURE_2*].

My normal dataframe has far more than a million rows and 16 columns, so I need a performance-optimized solution, please.

I need the split urgently for later processing.

**FIGURE_1** current dataframe

```
PacketID    TraceTime   Size
0   0.3948  --  --
1   0.3949  01.01.1970 00:12:39.298 77
2   0.3950  01.01.1970 00:12:39.298 80
3   0.3951  01.01.1970 00:12:39.315 81
4   0.3952  01.01.1970 00:12:39.335 78
5   0.3953  01.01.1970 00:12:39.335 71
.   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .
395926  7.11074 01.01.1970 00:48:42.829 1666
395927  7.11075 01.01.1970 00:48:42.829 57
395928  7.11076 01.01.1970 00:48:42.851 57
395929  #----- END: log_0000.log: session #0        
395930  #----- BEGIN: log_0000.log: session #1      
395931  PacketID    TraceTime   Size
395932  7.14891 --  --
395933  7.14892 01.01.1970 00:00:19.313 80
395934  7.14893 01.01.1970 00:00:19.313 61
.   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .
753533  13.19876    01.01.1970 00:31:56.374 60
753534  13.19877    01.01.1970 00:31:56.380 57
753535  13.19878    01.01.1970 00:31:56.380 57
753536  #----- END: log_0000.log: session #1        
753537  #----- BEGIN: log_0000.log: session #2      
753538  PacketID    TraceTime   Size
753539  13.23802    --  --
753540  13.23803    01.01.1970 00:00:48.777 17
753541  13.23804    01.01.1970 00:00:48.802 1
and so on...
```

**FIGURE_2**  desired dataframes

```
df_1 = 
PacketID    TraceTime   Size
0   0.3948  --  --
1   0.3949  01.01.1970 00:12:39.298 77
2   0.3950  01.01.1970 00:12:39.298 80
.   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .
395919  7.11067 01.01.1970 00:48:42.602 38
395920  7.11068 01.01.1970 00:48:42.602 54
395921  7.11069 01.01.1970 00:48:42.602 38
395922  7.11070 01.01.1970 00:48:42.629 57

df_2 =
395931  PacketID    TraceTime   Size
395932  7.14891 --  --
395933  7.14892 01.01.1970 00:00:19.313 80
395934  7.14893 01.01.1970 00:00:19.313 61
395935  7.14894 01.01.1970 00:00:19.313 110
.   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .
753532  13.19875    01.01.1970 00:31:56.374 63
753533  13.19876    01.01.1970 00:31:56.374 60
753534  13.19877    01.01.1970 00:31:56.380 57
753535  13.19878    01.01.1970 00:31:56.380 57

df_3 = 
753538  PacketID    TraceTime   Size
753539  13.23802    --  --
753540  13.23803    01.01.1970 00:00:48.777 17
753541  13.23804    01.01.1970 00:00:48.802 1
and so on...
```

I already have an option [*FIGURE_3*], but it is deprecated and will be removed in the future.

**FIGURE_3**

```
Python:
dense_ts = df['TraceTime']    
sparse_ts = dense_ts.to_sparse()
block_locs = zip(sparse_ts.sp_index.blocs, sparse_ts.sp_index.blengths)
blocks = [dense_ts.iloc[start:(start + length - 1)] for (start, length) in block_locs] 

Warning:
C:\Users\andre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:15: FutureWarning: Series.to_sparse is deprecated and will be removed in a future version from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

If your Dataframe needs to be split into several groups at a row containing all NaNs, here's a way:

```
#create groups by comparing to null  
df['group'] = df.isnull().all(axis=1).cumsum() 

# Use dictionary comprehension together with loc to select the relevant group
d = {i: df.loc[df.group == i, ['PacketID', 'TraceTime','Size']] for i in range(1, df.group.iat[-1])}
```